# Spotify JavaScript API song end/start events with the new API

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Is there any way to listen to events on track end, current time and track start with the new Spotify Api.

I have the following code

```
models.player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function(
  console.debug(event);                
});
```

But, returns an error with "Cannot read property 'CHANGE' of undefined". 
And of course the observer is called within require(...models ...)

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself. This is the new API to listen to changes.

models.player.addEventListener('change', updateNowPlayingWidget);

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-activity-activity.html